# Sling Dynamic Include Not Working for Multiple components

Tags: caching, osgi, aem, dispatcher, sling

I'm configuring SDI OSGi config, referencing - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/foundation/development/set-up-sling-dynamic-include.html?lang=en

The issue I'm facing is that:

If I set Only 1 resource type in the config property -

include-filter.config.resource-types="[my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic]" - it works.

But if I set more than 1 resource type in the config property -

include-filter.config.resource-types="[my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic, my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic2,my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic3]" - SDI works for only first entry(my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic) and not the others.

So if I reverse the sequence,

include-filter.config.resource-types="[my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic3, my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic2,my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic]" - SDI still works for only first entry(my-app/components/content/highly-dynamic3) and not the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue sounds related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-10289 which affects the current version 3.2.0.

Comment: Ok. So I've reverted to v3.1.2 and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @nik-8000 - Have you ever faced a situation or are aware of the scenario where SDI config updates are not real-time and changes are often reflected late (not just by few minutes but more than that)

Comment: Hi @abhishek-sinha, no, haven't seen this behaviour yet.

Comment: Hi Nik - thanks for the response. Can you please check this one as well? Apparently barely someone is using SDI an now i think why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401728/sling-dynamic-include-sdi-for-components-rendered-from-iparsys-in-aem-is-not-w